# Identify row or column addition or deletion in a table

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms

I'm looking for a solution which can able to identify the any row or column addition or deletion in a table of numbers.

What I have thought of as of now by using the LCS i.e. "Longest common sub-sequence" algorithm I can find out the common sub-sequence between two versions of a table but this method is not 100% correct.

*For e.g.*

**Table version 1**

```
 1 2 4 5 9 3
 4 9 3 7 5 3
 8 2 7 9 3 8
 9 7 2 8 2 4
```

After update, I remove 1 row (2nd row) and added 1 row (at same place i.e. 2nd).

**Table Version 2**

```
 1 2 4 5 9 3
 4 9 5 7 5 3
 8 2 7 9 3 8
 9 7 2 8 2 4
```

Added row is almost similar except 1 cell item. In this case LCS would not work as it most of the cell items would be similar and I can't able to identify row was removed first and a new row was added.

Comment: I edited your question to be about tables of numbers, rather than specifically Excel files. If your question is specific to Excel, it's off-topic, here, but would probably be fine on [so].

Comment: You could compute and store a [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) of each row and column (but that's probably overkill and there should be a better solution).

Comment: You should be able to generalize the idea of longest common subsequence to this situation, taking four operations (adding and deleting rows and columns).  The subtle twist is that you can only add a row or column if the dimensions match.  You should be able to calculate this with a dynamic programming algorithm.

Comment: Yes @DanielMcLaury I have also similar thoughts. And during my initial test my algorithm based on LCS is seems to be working fine. Thanks for your thought.